# python win32com Dispatch fails with 'CrystalRuntime.Application' (64bit issue)

Tags: python, crystal-reports, 64-bit

The essential details here are as follows:

- Windows Server 2008 64bit
- Python26 64bit
- Visual Studio 2008(Team) which installs Crystal Reports (both 32bit and 64bit runtimes)

My problem is the following code fails when **Dispatch('CrystalRuntime.Application')** is called, this worked fine on same 32bit OS configuration of the above.

The error being:

```
(-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

I've spent hours going through various reason why this is failing and I've got nowhere..

I've even run makepy.py on the *'Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer Run Time Library'* which contains the com interface I'm trying to create, but even this fails to deliver a result.

I know crystal is installed correctly as it works perfectly well and I can see the com classes registered correctly.

I completely stuck and need help, as always i hope stack can come to my rescue again...

Any thoughts, please bear in mind i'm not a python programmer of any magnitude...

```
import os
import sys
import re
import time
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import pythoncom

def main():

    try:
        app = Dispatch('CrystalRuntime.Application')
        print app
    except pythoncom.com_error, e:
        print "(crystal reports not installed?): '%s'" % e
        return 0

    print 'Success!!!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: OK, got a little further analysing this.

If I do more or less the same in a vb script file, and call the script file with 'cscript.exe', initially I get the same result. However, if I call the vb script file using the 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe' which I believe runs this script as a 32bit process, it works.

So..... what do I need to do to get the python script to behave the same, as i dont want to re-write the whole script in vb, just for the sake of a few line which dont work.

Answer (score 0):

When I use py26 with Excel, I've found that this syntax works better.

```
Excel_App = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

Maybe that can be altered to fit crystal reports..

```
App= win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('CrystalRuntime.Application')
```